# Execute a python prog that read a list of argument file

Tags: python, pandas, file, arguments

My prog extract a text file from an URL.
In the URL needs, there is a pattern of 5 letters, a user and a password. The rest is totally the same on almost 120 URL.

```
import pandas as pd

sta = 'router1'
usr = 'user'
pwd = 'password'
url ="http://"+sta+".someurl/alotofsyntax&usr="+usr+"&pwd="+pwd+"&command=dothis"

status = pd.read_csv(url, sep=':', on_bad_lines='skip', skipinitialspace = True)
```

So that work for a single router, now I want to automatise it on 120 routers, with a file which would contain something like

```
router1, user1, pawssword1
router2, user2, pawssword2
router3, user3, pawssword3
```

etc.

Comment: Use the `csv` module to parse the file. Then put your code in a loop that iterates over the file.

Comment: Please show what you tried and we'll help you get it working. We won't write it for you.

Comment: Just use a `f-string` to construct each URL; along the lines of `my_url = f"http://{sta}/alotofsyntax"` with the variables inside { } as you require and read from some data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've done it this way :
I made a file with two columns, user (sta) and password (pwd) and add something I forgot in the first send :

```
        x = 0
        end = len(codex)
        while x != end:   
        
            sta = codex['sta'][x]
            
            if len(codex['pwd'][x])!=0 :
                #special
                pwd = codex['pwd'][x]
            else:
                pwd = str('bla'+str(codex['sta'][x]))
            ... prog ...
            x+=1
```

Most of the time, the password was generated with some user characters, so it's generic, but sometime for some reason, there is special password, and so if in the file there is a blank, it's a generic pwd, if it's specified, it's used this one.

And in the while loop, there is the rest of my prog.

Sorry for have not been very clear in the first place but it wasn't very clear for myself, so ...